# 50Hz noise affecting my oscilloscope and i want to know how to stop it

Tags: noise, oscilloscope, circuit-design

I need help my oscilloscope keeps showing 50HZ 40mV Noise when the probe is not connected to any circuit,
I think The probe is working as an antenna for the 50hz from the power line ! 
How can i stop this because im trying to measure low voltages and frequencies! 
My oscilloscope is Hantek Dso5102p 50hz/220V

Comment: When it is not connected, it doesn't matter what it is showing.  When you connect it, the 50Hz goes away.

Comment: How low is low voltage?

Answer (score 1):

As you say your probe is an antenna. With an open high impedance end it can develop a few millivolts simply from mains pickup. Once you connect that end to your circuit that high impedance point goes away and most of the pickup.

If it does not you could consider getting a better quality lead but I dont really think that will be necessary unless the one you have is really bad.

As an additional practical suggestion route mains cables well away from your test rigs

Comment: Probes are the ones that came with it when I bought it, and no the noise didnt vanish when i connected it to the circuit trying to test my signal, should i have any thing connected to the power lines other than the oscilloscope removed from the room?

Comment: What is the impedance of the signal you are trying to measure are you using the probe ground clip to the ground on your circuit somewhere near the measurement point.